# PHP mail() function auto-respond

Tags: php, email, forms

I'm using PHP's mail() function on a form to send an e-mail to an address that has an auto-respond.  Unfortunately, since the e-mail is generated from a form, it tries to reply to www.domain.com@web.pas.earthlink.net, which doesn't exist, and bounces back.

```
mail("info@domain.com", $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

other info:

```
$email_from = "forms@domain.com";

$headers = "From: ".$email_from;
$headers .= "\nReply-To: ".$email_from;
$headers .= "\nReturn-Path: ".$email_from;
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
```

Is there any way to fix this?  How can I set a proper return address?

edit: I should say that when the response arrives, the reply-to address IS set correctly to $email_from.  Regardless, the auto-responder still tries sending it to www.domain.com@web.pas.earthlink.net.

Comment: what's the auto responder? it depends on how the auto responder is reading the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Return-Path is not like other mail headers. It's a so called "envelope header". Those are set by the MTA, not by fields in the header part of the actual mail. Most MTAs have a special flag for setting the Return-Path. In Postfix, Sendmail and Exim it's the `f` flag, so on those systems you can usually call `mail` like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers, '-f'.$email_from);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Return-Path` (if that's what you mean) with the [fifth parameter](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> bool mail ( string $to , string
>   $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string
>   $additional_parameters ]] )

... where:

> additional_parameters (optional)
>
> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass
>   additional flags as command line
>   options to the program configured to
>   be used when sending mail, as defined
>   by the sendmail_path configuration
>   setting. For example, this can be used
>   to set the envelope sender address
>   when using sendmail with the -f
>   sendmail option.
>
> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user
>   to the sendmail configuration to
>   prevent a 'X-Warning' header from
>   being added to the message when the
>   envelope sender (-f) is set using this
>   method. For sendmail users, this file
>   is /etc/mail/trusted-users.

Setting it to `-finfo@domain.com` should do the trick.

In any case, I believe that the auto-responder should be using the address from the `From` header (if not `Reply-To` provided) but, oh well... :)